# How to take input from text file for adjacency matrix in c language

Tags: c

Here is the inline input for my code.

```
int graph[V][V] = {{0, 2, 0, 6, 0},
                  {2, 0, 3, 8, 5},
                  {0, 3, 0, 0, 7},
                  {6, 8, 0, 0, 9},
                  {0, 5, 7, 9, 0},
                 };
```

I want to take this graph input from the text file to the graph array.

Comment: perhaps you forgot to post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

If the file contains single digit numbers, then you can use this code which I used once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int v;
    printf("Please enter the value of v ");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    int** graph = malloc(sizeof(int*)*v);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<v;i++) 
        graph[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*v);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input","r");
    char c;
    for(i=0;i<v;i++) {
          for(j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, " %c", &c);
            graph[i][j] = c-'0';
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<v;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<v;j++) {
            printf("%d ",graph[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to cast  `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks. I always thought it returns a void pointer.

Comment: yes indeed! that's the reason why you don't need to cast the value of `malloc`